# Eloquent Laravel multiple like where and where clause

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have the below Mysql query that works.

mysql:

```
select * from operatories op
left join locations al on op.location = al.location
where op.opname like '%NP%' or op.opname like '%OPEN%'
and  al.isOfficeClosed = 0;
```

This works and i get the data that I expected but I am trying to write that in Laravel query builder but its not picking up the last `and` al.isOfficeClose = 0.  is there anything you all can catch and see that I am doing wrong?

Laravel:

```
    $locs = DB::table('operatories as op')
        ->leftJoin(DB::raw('locations al'), function($join) {
            $join->on('op.Location', '=', 'al.location');

        })
        ->Where('op.opname','LIKE','%NP%')
        ->orWhere('op.opname','LIKE','%OPEN%')
        ->where('al.isOfficeClosed', '=','0');
```

Comment: Maybe the uppercasse on `op.Location` makes the join fail?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ nope, I tried that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a function for `where` clause, like this:

```
$locs = DB::table('operatories as op')
    ->leftJoin(DB::raw('locations al'), function($join) {
        $join->on('op.Location', '=', 'al.location');

    })
    ->where(function($q) { 
         $q->where('op.opname','LIKE','%NP%');
         $q->orWhere('op.opname','LIKE','%OPEN%');
    })
    ->where('al.isOfficeClosed', '=','0');
```

By the way,

```
select * from operatories op
left join locations al on op.location = al.location
where op.opname like '%NP%' or op.opname like '%OPEN%'
  and  al.isOfficeClosed = 0;
```

is different than (mind the parenthesis)

```
select * from operatories op
left join locations al on op.location = al.location
where (op.opname like '%NP%' or op.opname like '%OPEN%')
  and  al.isOfficeClosed = 0;
```